# Extracting geometrical patterns from an image with complex drawings

Tags: image, image-recognition

We have a big sample size of drawings with different geometrical forms. Imagine that most of them only contain circumferences and straight lines. Is there a technique of pattern recognition for counting the number of circumferences and lines in each image? Here an example:[image]

So that we can say that there are approximately 4 circumferences and 2 straight lines?  I find this quite difficult with the current techniques due to the "complexity" (e.g. superposition of the geometrical forms) of the drawings, but has someone any idea? The problem is that we have more than 2000 samples... Any help is welcome. I mostly work with R and Matlab.